# How to transform category variable to dummy/indicator variable in MLBase

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to use logistic regression model in MLBase to predict CTR of Ad. In my dataset I have some category variables and I want to transform them to dummy/indicator variables used as input of model. My data looks like

```
"log_time","country","gender"
"2015-05-19","USA","M"
"2015-05-20","IND","F"
```

Are there some solution to complete the transformation in MLBase or scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [one hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot).

Spark's [MLlib has a one hot encoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) which can do this for you.